# Scanner recognised by lsusb but not by scanimage

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, fujitsu-siemens

I have a fully supported scanner, a Fujitsu ScanSnap 1500M (04c5:11a2) on a USB3 connection. It is recognised when I type lsusb. It is recognised in dmesg. It is recognised when I type sane-find-scanner. It is present in /etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf. It is enabled in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf. I am a member of the group saned. I have tried the [USB3 workaround](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane_Troubleshooting#The_USB3_Issue). But still, when I use scanimage -L,Xsane or Document Scanner, I get nothing - no scanner recognised. I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 with libsane 1.0.31.

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me insane! Your help will be most gratefully received!

Comment: And here is my udev rule:

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FUJITSU", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04c5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="11a2", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

And I am a member of scanner.

Comment: $ lsusb<br><br>
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. ES603 Swipe Fingerprint Sensor<br>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04c5:11a2 Fujitsu, Ltd ScanSnap S1500<br><br>
$ sudo SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1 sudo scanimage -L<br>
No scanners were identified. <br><br>
$ sane-find-scanner<br>
found USB scanner (vendor=0x1c7a [EgisTec], product=0x0603 [EgisTec_ES603]) at libusb:001:004<br>
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5, product=0x11a2) at libusb:001:003

Comment: Same scanner on a different laptop (running Linux MInt 20) and it works out the box - but it uses USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: Tried plugging the scanner into a USB 2.0 hub and the hub into my laptop - same results as before.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, it is a particular sequence that is needed:

1. unplug the scanner from the USB3 port
2. open a terminal and enter SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1
3. plug the scanner back into the USB3 port
4. Voila! The scanner is now identified by scanimage -L

Comment: I fail to see how the position of #2 in this list could possibly matter, other than having it be before #4.  Regardless, even when trying exactly that, it didn't work for me.  Will try some of the other things you list in your question, though.  Thanks.